hook_field_widget_form_alter() not retaining form field value when "Add another item" button is clicked
My hook_field_widget_form_alter() implementation looks as follows,
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter() {
  $field_definition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
  if ($field_definition instanceof FieldConfig) {
    $config = $field_definition->id();
    list($entity_type, $bundle, $field_name) = explode('.', $config);
    if ($entity_type == 'paragraph' && ($field_name == 'field_add_unique')) {
      $element['#type'] = 'textfield';
      $element['#autocomplete_route_name'] = 'mymodule.campaign-prod-unqiue-autocomplete';
      $element['#autocomplete_route_parameters'] = [];
    }
  }
}

In the entity create form I get the auto-completed populated as desired for the first time.
However, the field_add_unique is a multi-value field when I hit the "Add another item" button, the AJAX refresh causes the field to reset its previously entered text field value.
Any suggestions to retain already entered data will be appreciated.

Changing the autocomplete route should be no problem, but I wouldn't set a different field type unless you want to adjust the rest of the code necessary to build and submit the form element.

It is changing the $element as following resolved the issue.
$element['value']['#autocomplete_route_name'] = 'mymodule.campaign-prod-unqiue-autocomplete';
